# Is there any FOSS lib for reading Excel files using C

Tags: c, objective-c, excel, macos

As the title says, I am looking for source code that shows how to read(write) MS Excel files in pure C (OS agnostic). I have seen some Java code (e.g. JExcel) and would use that if I can't find some existing C code with similar functionality.

What I need is to read an Excel file and convert it to XML (or some other more manageable format).

TIA

Answer (score 1):

It's a pain. I'd use TSV unless you *really* need native Excel.